# Why can't I access the controller object in RSpec when testing a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm using rspec-rails, version 1.2.6. In a controller test

```
describe WebsController do ...
```

I don't seem to have access to the controller object in order to stub methods. For example, the following won't work:

```
  before :all do
    @feed = mock_model(Feed)
    controller.should_receive(:feed_from_params).and_return @feed    
  end
```

I get warnings like

```
An expectation of :feed_from_params was set on nil.
```

and firing up a debug session from the spec tells on the line just before the method mock, I get the following:

```
(rdb:1) self.respond_to? :controller
true
(rdb:1) controller
nil
```

From all the examples, accessing the controller variable should work, but it doesn't. What gives? How can I mock or stub methods in a controller under test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the :all in the before block fixes the issue. Not sure why, though.

```
before do
...
end
```

is what you need.

Comment: The reason for this is that a before(:all) block is run _once_ at system startup, whereas a before() (which is really a before(:each)) block is run before each test, and happens _after_ any before(:each) blocks defined in an outer context.

Answer (score 3):

Try using @controller rather than controller

Answer (score 1):

If you need `controller` in a `before(:all)` block, call `setup_controller_request_and_response`.

Answer (score 0):

PS: This behavior should be fixed in recent versions of RSpec.

See a [running example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec#controller-is-exposed-to-global-before-hooks) from RSpec v.2.14:

```
require "spec_helper"

RSpec.configure {|c| c.before { expect(controller).not_to be_nil }}

describe WidgetsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "doesn't matter" do
    end
  end
end
```